# Removing the value from array after unchecking the checkbox in LWC

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I have a html table in which there is a lightning-input type checkbox for each row of the table in the child component. On checking the checkbox the row id is passed to the parent component and pushed in to the array. When I uncheck that checkbox the row Id is still present in the array. I want a solution that whenever I check the checkbox the row id is pushed to the array and whenever I uncheck it, the row id should be removed from the array.

**Child component code:**

HTML

```
<lightning-input class="input-checkbox" onchange={handleChange} type="checkbox" value={row.Id} data-id={row.Id} </lightning-input>
```

JS

```
handleChange(event) {
const customEventCheck = new CustomEvent('childevent', {
detail:event.target.value
});
this.dispatchEvent(customEventCheck);
}
```

**Parent Component Code:**

HTML (calling child component)

```
<template for:each={tableList} for:item={item} >
<child-component key={item.Id} row={item} onchildevent={storeid} >
</child-component>
</template>
```

JS

```
@track checkedId=[];

storeid(event){
var rowId = event.detail;
this.checkedId.push(rowId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send an attribute in event which will tell you whether the checkbox is checked or not like this

```
const customEventCheck = new CustomEvent('childevent', {
detail:{val:event.target.value,checked:event.target.checked}
});
```

and in parent based on that value you can add or remove the element

```
var rowId = event.detail.val;
var checked=event.detail.checked;

if(checked){
this.checkedId.push(rowId);
}else{
    var index = this.checkedId.indexOf(rowId);
this.checkedId.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @User6670 you need to pass the additional attribute to store the checkbox value.

In addition to `splice`, you can also use the `filter` method to remove the unchecked record.

```
storeid(event){
    if(event.detail.checked){
         this.checkedId.push(event.detail.val);
    } else {
         this.checkedId = this.checkedId.filter(rowId => rowId !== event.detail.val);
    }
}
```